What is a closed-form expression for the number of matrix multiplications in this repeated squaring algorithm?
I was wondering if anyone could provide a closed form expression for the amount of matrix multiplications performed as a function of $n$ in the following algorithm to compute $X^n$ for some matrix $X$:
\begin{array}{l}
\texttt{def matrix_exp($X,n$):} \\
\texttt{if $n=0$ return $I$} \\
\texttt{if $n=1$ return $X$} \\
\texttt{if $n$ is even return matrix_exp($X, \frac n 2$)$\cdot$matrix_exp($X, \frac n 2$)}\\
\texttt{if $n$ is odd return $X \cdot $matrix_exp($X, \lfloor \frac n 2 \rfloor$)$\cdot$matrix_exp($X, \lfloor \frac n 2 \rfloor$)}
\end{array}
The reason why I am asking this is because I am trying to justify to myself why the number of matrix multiplications is $O(\log n)$ here (a claim my textbook makes).

Slight modifications are made below to make it $O(\log n)$:
\begin{array}{l}
\texttt{def matrix_exp($X,n$):} \\
\texttt{if $n=0$ return $I$} \\
\texttt{if $n=1$ return $X$} \\
\texttt{if $n$ is even [ $a$ = matrix_exp($X, \frac n 2$); return $a\cdot a$ ]}\\
\texttt{if $n$ is odd [ $a$ = matrix_exp($X, \lfloor \frac n 2 \rfloor$); return $X\cdot a\cdot a$ ]}
\end{array}

For $n=2^k$, only the even case will be called and each call consumes one matrix multiplication. The total number of multiplications is $\log_2(n)=k$. This is the most efficient case.

For $n=2^k-1$, only the odd case will be called and each call consumes two matrix multiplications. The total number of multiplications is  $2[\log_2(n+1)-1]=2k-2$. This is the least efficient case.

All other cases are bounded between the above two extremes.



How can we formally reason that other cases are bounded by these two extremes? It certainly seems intuitively true, but I was struggling to formally justify this.

@PrincessMia Other cases with $2^{k-1}+1\leq n\leq 2^k-2$ will involve calls from some even and some odd situations. So the average number of multiplications per iteration is between 1 and 2. But the number of iterations is bounded by $k-1$. Thus, the total number cannot exceed $2k-2$.

For $n \geq 1$ it requires $n-1$ multiplications, and of course for $n=0$ it requires 0.
This can be proven by strong induction.
Base case: Note that for $n=1$ by the special case there are no matrix multiplications and therefore the formula holds.
Inductive step: Now suppose that computing $X^n$ uses $n-1$ multiplications for every $n \leq m$ for some $m$. There are two cases two consider
Case 1: $m+1$ is even: If $m+1$ is even then the procedure computes $X^{(m+1)/2}$ twice (once for each call) and each of these by the inductive assumption uses $(m+1)/2 - 1$ calls. Since this is done twice it uses
$$2 \left [ (m+1)/2 - 1\right ] = m+1 - 2 = m-1$$
matrix multiplications in the calls. In addition it is required to use 1 more multiplication two compute $X^{(m+1)/2}X^{(m+1)/2} = X^{m+1}$ and this gives $m-1+1 = m$ total multiplications and we see that in this case the formula holds.
Case 2: m+1 is odd: If $m+1$ is odd then $\lfloor (m+1)/2 \rfloor = (m+1)/2 - 1/2 = m/2$ and by assumption that means constructing $X^{\lfloor (m+1)/2 \rfloor} = X^{m/2}$ takes $m/2-1$ multiplications to construct. Again this is performed twice which gives
$$2(m/2 - 1) = m - 2$$
multiplications to construct the two copies of $X^{\lfloor (m+1)/2 \rfloor}$. In addition there are 2 more multiplications which come from $XX^{\lfloor (m+1)/2 \rfloor}X^{\lfloor (m+1)/2 \rfloor}$ and give a total of $m-2+2 = m$ total multiplications and again the formula holds.
Side Note This algorithm is actually quite inefficient for constructing matrix exponentials and it is possible to use $O(\log n)$ many multiplications to construct the matrix exponential.

hmm actually my text claimed that the above algorithm is $O(\log n)$ (I made a typo with originally attributing $O(n)$ to be the claim of my text). Maybe they made a mistake
